# I'm having an issue with my .htaccess redirection

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to use this url http://yoursite.com/proprietes.php?viewid&mls=[18348939] but I wan it to go on a pdf a-very-new-post.pdf. I want to do a redirection in the htaccess. It is not working... I'm in wordpress
thanks!

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /proprietes.php?viewid&mls=[18348939]$ http://yoursite.com/a-very-new-post.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` or `RewriteRule` directives cannot match query string. Use a `RewriteCond` instead like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/proprietes\.php\?viewid&mls=\[?18348939\]? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /a-very-new-post.pdf? [L,B,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/en/proprietes\.php\?viewid&mls=\[?18348939\]? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /a-very-new-post-english.pdf? [L,B,R=301]
```

Comment: it is still not working... but I get your thinking will work on it thanks!

Comment: That URL is working fine with exact same rules on my Apache. Make sure this rule is first rule in your .htaccess just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: that was my issue it was not the first rule thanks a lot

Comment: hey last question I have to redirect the url  
/en/proprietes.php?viewid&mls=[18348939] to a different pdf but it is going to /a-very-new-post.pdf. How can do so it goes to /a-very-new-post-english.pdf ? thanks again

Comment: it works perfectly do you know where I could find good documentation on .htaccess I don't found simple documentation on google...

Comment: [Check this blog](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)